# Find a value corresponding to first occurance of name

Tags: python, pandas

[Image of Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6DkN.png)

I want to extract the values of Date corresponding to the first occurrence of the USA without using a loop and I have already mapped the data in a pandas datagram.
Find the image of the dataset in the above link.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the dataframe from lists, and applying a boolean mask for the Country,
we can select the first date value by slicing the resulting data structure with the zero-index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["USA", "04-04-2020", 5000],
    ["USA", "05-04-2020", 7500],
    ["India", "04-04-2020", 2300]
    ], columns = ["Country", "Date", "Amount"]
    )

filt = df["Country"] == "USA"

print(df[filt].Date[0])
```

Outputs:

```
04-04-2020
```